# Is "erinnern" irregular?

Tags: verb, irregular-verb

I learned that most infinitives end in *-en*, with the exception of irregulars like *sein*. Is the verb *erinnern* (*to remind*) also irregular? Are there any other verbs whose infinitive ends in -ern? If so, what are they — regular or irregular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The three common infinitive endings of German verbs are -en, -eln, and -ern. As you already wrote, verbs ending in -en are in the far majority. But the other two are also common:

> -eln: e.g. handeln, hebeln, grübeln, gründeln, makeln, lächeln, wechseln … "googeln"
>
> -ern: e.g. ackern, ändern, ärgern, blättern, dauern, eiern, feiern, flimmern, rudern, stochern

The complete list would be pages long. To help you making a guess what the infinitive is, these verbs often have a related noun ending in -el or -er.

Comment: That is very good to know, and a well-presented answer. Danke!

Comment: I did not get the idea of using a related noun to guess the infinitive form of the verb. Ruder --> rudern, okay. As opposed to Grund - gründeln. But ändern? flimmern? stochern?

Comment: *Hentschel, Weydt: Handbuch der deutschen Grammatik, 4. Aufl., S. 127.*